# How to change position of element when onclick using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have two divs, `.div_data` and `.div_update` where

```
<select name=change_placement>
    <option value=0>Top</option>
    <option value=1>Bottom</option>
</select>

<div class='div_data'>Data Data</div>
<div class='div_update'>
    <form name=stuff>
        <input type=text>
    </form>
</div>
```

How do I get `.div_update` to precede `.div_data` when clicking on `select[name=change_placement]`?

Comment: Do you mean to say when choosing an option in the select ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put an id to your select and also added an option 'Select' to your dropdown select. I am assuming that you want the input text box to go above the other div when you choose 'Top'.

```js
$('#change_placement').on('change', function() {
   var option = $(this).val();
   if(option == 0) {
     $('.div_update').insertBefore($('.div_data'));
   } else {
     $('.div_update').insertAfter($('.div_data'));
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='change_placement' id='change_placement'>
 <option value=''>Select</option>
 <option value='0'>Top</option>
 <option value='1'>Bottom</option>
</select>

<div class='div_data'>
 Data
 Data
</div>
<div class='div_update'>
 <form name=stuff>
  <input type=text>
 </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `insertBefore` and `insertAfter` functions

```js
$(function(){
   $('select').on('change', function(){
      var value = $(this).val();
      if(value == "1") {
        
        $('.div_update').insertAfter('.div_data');
      } else {
          $('.div_update').insertBefore('.div_data');
      }
   });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name=change_placement>
 <option value="0">Top</option>
 <option value="1">Bottom</option>
</select>

<div class='div_data'>
 Data
 Data
</div>
<div class='div_update'>
 <form name=stuff>
  <input type=text>
 </form>
</div>
```

*emphasized text*

Answer (score 0):

Quick play fixed issue:

```
if(update_ticket_placement == 0) {
    var myparent = $('div.div_update');
    var parentparent = $('div.div_data');
    myparent.detach().prependTo(parentparent );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) to inserting targer element after specific element.

```
$("select").change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(".div_update").insertAfter(value == 1 ? ".div_data" : this);  
});
```

```js
$("select").change(function(){
    $(".div_update").insertAfter($(this).val() == 1 ? ".div_data" : this);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name=change_placement>
    <option value=0>Top</option>
    <option value=1>Bottom</option>
</select>
<div class='div_update'>
    <form name=stuff>
        <input type=text>
    </form>
</div>
<div class='div_data'>Data Data</div>
```